# How to obtain an object with mongodb driver 3.4.2 from c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have problems to obtains objects in C#. I use mongo driver 2.4.3.

I have this code:

```
    public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        IMongoCollection<Employee> collection = conectWithDatabase();

        var filter = Builders<Employee>.Filter.Eq("EmployeeId", id);
        var obtenido = collection.Find(filter).First();

        return obtenido;
    }
```

and this

```
    public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        IMongoCollection<Employee> collection = conectWithDatabase();
        var query = from employee in collection.AsQueryable<Employee>()
                    select employee;
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

In the first code when I call GetEmplyee method the program show this exception

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se pueden crear las instancias de 
    clases abstractas.' -> in this line collection.Find(filter).First();
```

And in the second code the program show the same exception when i try to cast the query var to list.

I try to get an object from a MongoDB and i can't if someone can help me i will be very grateful. 
Sorry my bad english.

```
public abstract class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}

public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
{
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}

public class PartTimeEmployee : Employee
{
    public double HourlyRate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your exception is "Unable to create abstract class instances". So most likely is that Employee class is declared as abstract. Show this class declaration please?

Comment: Yes Employee is abstract I have FullTimeEmployee and PartTimeEmployee. But I don't know the type of Employee that the database give me to work. I update the question
@JleruOHeP

Comment: Please take a look here http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/

Answer (score 0):

At a basic level.. You need to map the discriminator column and then match type based on that.

Driver should be able to do this for you

[Inheritance in MongoDb: how to request instances of defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405887/inheritance-in-mongodb-how-to-request-instances-of-defined-type)

Comment: The problem its that i don't know the type of Employee that the database give me in the result of query.

Comment: Then map a discriminator column and match with nameof (typeof class) and then cast

Comment: OK. Bue The problem its that i can't take the employee and i try to implement the code as your example in the link and it isn't work. I can't take the employee to cast it.